# ColdFusion SQLServer Error "Your connection was terminated."

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, sql-server-2012, coldfusion-11

I keep getting the following error in my ColdFusion Administrator log file:

> Error Executing Database Query. [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver]Your connection was terminated.

And for the life of me I can't seem to figure out why. There are no indicators in the SQL Server log files that a connection was closed. It happens at random times, but usually about 3-5 times per day.

I am running ColdFusion 11 and SQL Server 2012 SP1 Web

Comment: How often you get this message? Have you checked 'Timeout' setting under CF Administrator > Datasources?

Comment: Is your SQL connection managed in the Administrator or in your application somewhere?

Comment: I get the message about 3-5 times per day and it varies each time. Sometimes its within an our or two of each error, sometimes its 6-8 hours.

Comment: Yes the SQL connection is managed through the CF Admin. The timeout (min) is 7 minutes and Interval (min) is 7 minutes. Also the Login Timeout is 180 sec.

Comment: Does it reconnect automatically, or you need to do anything?

Comment: I don't have it limiting connections, and new connections seem to work fine. It just happens during some requests. So the connection being used by a request is terminated and the request throws and error. But the next request through uses a new connection and works fine. The server gets thousands of requests per day so the error only happens on like 3-5 of them. It's a small problem but I'd like to try and figure out why.